# Dropdown List is not Updating the Selected Value (SemanticUI)

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I am using SemanticUI for a dropdown list

```
<div class="ui dropdown">
  <input type="hidden" name="gender">
  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  <div class="default text">Gender</div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="item" data-value="male">Male</div>
    <div class="item" data-value="female">Female</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

in the bottom of my page, I am initializing it as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
});
```

The problem is that when a user selects an item, it does not update and it keeps showing the default value as selected. 
But when I go to Chrome Console and execute the above code JQuery(document)..., then it works fine.

I am assuming it is due to that the initialization needs to execute after page loads completely. So, What I did is the following instead of the above:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.ui.dropdown')
  .dropdown()
;
});
});;
```

It worked. Dropdown list updates selection immediatly. However, when I click on Submit, I and page reloads, the selection is lost. 
The drop down is being used as a filter to table. Having the selection gets lost on submit, makes filter unusable.

What is the best way to go around this.

Comment: use plain html with autocomplete on

Comment: Thanks Walle. I did not get the idea. Note that I am modfying an interface to some complex script that is beyond my ability to change its structure. All I did here was changing css classes and initializing the dropdown to get it work and look like SemanticUI drop down. If I understand your point correctly, then this may require further changes on how the script reads the selected value. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX to submit the form so the page doesn't refresh.

Comment: I am sorry for being a newbie. I have the form <form method="get" id="urma-filter-form" class="block"> but how do I use AJAX for it. Thanks

Comment: There are lot of ajax tutorials for submitting forms. It would be better if you studied up on those and then asked specific questions later.

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <select>
    <option value="male">Male</option>
    <option value="female">Female</option>
</select>
```

no extra js, css required,

edit: autocomplete attribute is not required because it is the default

Comment: Thanks Walle. This is what I currently have before trying to use SemanticUI. I need to use SemanticUI and for that, I have to add Css and JS which causes the problem. Thanks